# How to set register page of network wordpress to my subdomain like my.site.com?

Tags: wordpress, networking, subdomain, multisite

I want to change my WordPress Multisite register page that is:

http://example.com/wp-signup.php?new=newsite

To my subdomain like:

http://my.example.com

Any help pls?

Comment: It solved by creating a new user named register on my subdomain and use a register form shortcode on it's main page.
Thank You

Answer (score -1):

go to the cpanel and create a subdomain..... kindly copy or move the wp... contents there... so it will be like new.example.com/wp-signup somehow like that... if you don't get it... I can help you with that

Comment: then my new users sites create as new.my.example.com?
but I want to register as new.example.com

Comment: no, it will just be a subdomain... which will be the name your want to use if its my. or new. depends on you

Comment: read this... it will help you sales-billing.everymanhosting.com/knowledgebase/25/How-to-create-and-add-subdomains-in-cPanel-.html

Comment: thanks Tolani, but problem is not creating and moving to a subdomain.  I want my base site remains example.com.

Comment: but url is important for me

Comment: please explain to me clearly, your question about the URL?

Comment: It solved by creating a new user named register on my subdomain and use a register form shortcode on it's main page.
Thank You Tolani